# How to set threshold value for Hough Transform

Tags: image-processing, hough-transform

I am new to Computer Vision, I am writing my own code for [Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) I have found the following algorithm:

**Algorithm:**

```
• The cell (i,j) corresponds to the square associated
with parameter values (θj, ρi).

• Initialize all cells with value 0.

• For each foreground point (xk,yk) in the thresholded
edge image
– Let θj equal all the possible θ-values

• Solve for ρ using ρ=x cos θj +ysin θj

• Round ρ to the closest cell value, ρq

• Increment A(i,q) if the θj results in ρq

• After this procedure, A(i,j)=P means that P points in
the xy-space lie on the line ρj=x cos θj +ysin θj

• Find line candiates where A(i,j) is above a suitable
threshold
```

I have written the code to increment the indices of hough accumulator array.

**My Code:**

```
%%
% Hough Transform

[rows,cols] = size(E); % size of edged image

rhomax = ceil (sqrt(rows^2 + cols^2)); % maximum value of rho

rhomax = rhomax * 2; % multuplied with 2 to cater both +rho and -rho values

accu = zeros(rhomax, 101); % initialization of accumulaor array with rhomax and 101 possible theta values

for i =1:1:rows % for all rows

    for j =1:1:cols % for all columns

        if(E(i,j) ~= 0) % if the pixel is ONE (part of the edge) then process it

            for theta = 85.0:0.1:95.0 % for the theta values 85.0 - 95.0

                % computing the theta index for hough accumulator
                theta_index = 0;
                for k =85.0:0.1:theta
                    theta_index = theta_index + 1;
                end
                %---

                rho = round (i*cos(theta) + j*sin(theta)); % computing the value of rho

                % computing the rho index for hough accumulator
                rho_index = 1;
                if(rho < 0)
                    rho_index = rho_index + abs(rho);
                elseif(rho > 0)
                    rho_index = rho_index + (rhomax/2) + rho;
                elseif(rho == 0)
                    rho_index = rho_index + (rhomax/2);
                end
                %---

                accu(rho_index,theta_index) = accu(rho_index,theta_index)+1; % incrementing the corresponding index in accumulator

            end

        end

    end

end
```

Now I want to proceed further with the threshold value. I will be very grateful if someone tell me **how should I select my threshold value ?**

Answer (score 3):

Well, it really depends on what you expect to find in the image.  [The matlab function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghpeaks.html) uses an example threshold of half the largest peak.

What sort of images are you using this on?

---

So, based on just finding vertical lines in your image, let's make some assumptions.

- Your rectangle's minimum vertical side length is $L_{\rm min}$ pixels.
- Your edge detection only finds 80% of each edge.

Then the minimum threshold will be 
$$
0.8 L_{\rm min}
$$

You many need to modify this if, for example, your edges tend to be thicker or thinner than the 80% figure.